# Adobe JavaScipt

Tags: javascript, adobe

Hello I would need help with some JavaScript not knowing much about it.

On an Adobe Acrobat DC file during a form I offer a 500 € pack including 3 options (the first 3 checkboxes by default) with the possibility of having an additional option free. We therefore offer 5 other options with a price of 250 €. My goal is that when a customer ticks his first box, it will be free and the amount of € 500 will not change, but if he ticks additional boxes, the price will be € 250. In summary I would like the first box checked to be free (not knowing the option he will choose) and that the boxes checked then add € 250 to € 500 (base price) in the “TOTAL” box. my checkboxes naming this: A, B, C, D, E.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XcJu.png)

Comment: Bonjour, c'est contre les regles de écrire en françcais sur ce site, veuillez mettre à jour votre question en anglais svp. Merci.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's written in French.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow: Please it's  forbidden to ask a question in any other  language than English. Suggest you to read  this article for more. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A starting point... I use a global function, you have to check and add your own logic.

```
 form1::initialize - (JavaScript, client)
xfa.form.form1.form.Total.rawValue = 500;
global.addTo = function (val) {
    xfa.form.form1.form.Total.rawValue = xfa.form.form1.form.Total.rawValue = 500 + val;
    if (xfa.form.form1.form.Total.rawValue < 500) {
        xfa.form.form1.form.Total.rawValue = 500;
    }
}

 form1.form.Option1::change - (JavaScript, client)
app.alert('form1.form.Option1::change');
if (xfa.form.form1.form.Option1.rawValue) {
    app.alert('Checked');
    global.addTo(250);
} else {
    global.addTo(-250);
}

 form1.form.Option2::change - (JavaScript, client)
app.alert('form1.form.Option2::change');
if (xfa.form.form1.form.Option2.rawValue) {
    app.alert('Checked');
    global.addTo(250);
} else {
    global.addTo(-250);
}

 form1.form.Option3::change - (JavaScript, client)
app.alert('form1.form.Option3::change');
if (xfa.form.form1.form.Option3.rawValue) {
    app.alert('Checked');
    global.addTo(250);
} else {
    global.addTo(-250);
}
```

Comment: Hey,
I finally found thank you
var cpt=0;

if (this.getField("A").value==1)
{
      cpt++;
}
if (this.getField("B").value==1)
{
      cpt++;
}
if (this.getField("C").value==1)
{
      cpt++;
}
if (this.getField("D").value==1)
{
      cpt++;
}
if (this.getField("E").value==1)
{
      cpt++;
}

var prixOptions = 0;

if (cpt>1) {
    prixOptions = 250 * (cpt-1);
}
this.getField("T").value = 500+ prixOptions;